# Is there a way to add things to a list in a for loop without initializing the list before the for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to sort a class with multiple attributes and putting each of them into a list. This is being used in a unit test to confirm my class is sorting them properly. Is there a way that I can create a list and add things to it on one line (like in list comprehension) inside of a for loop?

For instance, in order to sort them right now I have to either use something like this:

`objects` is a list of `Object` class items

```
red_objects = []
blue_objects = []
green_objects = []
for object in objects:
    if object.color == 'red':
        red_objects.append(object.name)
    elif object.color == 'blue':
        blue_objects.append(object.name)
    elif object.color == 'green':
        green_objects.append(object.name)
```

or something like this:

```
red_objects = [object.name for object in objects if object.color == 'red']
blue_objects = [object.name for object in objects if object.color == 'blue']
green_objects = [object.name for object in objects if object.color == 'green']
```

Obviously the second option is a lot cleaner, however I have to run through the loop three separate times. Is there some sort of way to combine the two method so I can only run through the loop once but I can create the lists in a similar way to list comprehension?

Comment: `collections.defaultdict` is very useful in cases like this.  After initializing `by_color = defaultdict(list)`, the body of your loop would just be `by_color[object.color].append(object.name)`.  The results are in `by_color['red']`, and so on.

Comment: @jasonharper I actually really like this solution. I was not aware that was how `defaultdict` worked and I can actually implement this elsewhere outside of my tests. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a `dict`:

```py
red_objects, blue_objects, green_objects = [],[],[]
my_dict = {'red': red_objects.append, 'blue': blue_objects.append, 'green': green_objects.append}

for object in objects:
    my_dict[object.color](object.name)
```